# binomial()$linkinv(fixef()) and binomial_pred_ci() functions: what exactly does these function are for when applied to mixed generalized analysis?

Tags: r, function

I was workinf on a dataset, trying re-perfomrming an already run statysical analysis and I met the following function:

```
binomial()$linkinv(fixef(m))
```

after running the following model

```
summary((m = glmer(T1.ACC ~ COND + (COND | ID), d9only, family = binomial)))
```

My first question is what exactly does this functions is made for? Beacuse throgh other command lines the reciprocal code as well as a slightly modified code based always on it are also reported:

```
1) 1- binomial()$linkinv(fixef())
2) d9only$fit = binomial()$linkinv(model.matrix(m) %*% fixef(m)) #also the sense of the operator %*% is quite misterious too.
```

Moreover, another function present is the following one:

```
binomial_pred_ci()
```

To be honest, I've to search through the overall script and no customized function there was or the package where that has been called from either? Anyone knows where does it may come from? Maybe the package 'runjags'? Just in case, any on how to download it?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: @Ben has already answered the question, but just to confirm that none of the functions/code you have in your question come from the runjags package, or would even work with models fit using JAGS. So I think the runjags tag is a red herring!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with most of @Oliver's answer.  I will add a few comments (since I had an answer partly composed already).

I would be **very wary** of the script you are following: some parts look wrong (I could obviously be mistaken since these bits are taken completely out of context ...)

- `binomial()$linkinv` refers to the *inverse link function* for the model used. By default (which applies in this case since no optional `link=` argument has been specified), this is the inverse-logit or logistic function A nearly equivalent function is available via `plogis()`, but using `$linkinv` could be better in some cases since it would generalize to binomial analyses done with other link functions [e.g. probit or cloglog].
- as @Oliver mentions, applying the inverse link function to the coefficients is at least weird, I would even say wrong. Researchers often *exponentiate* coefficients estimated on the logit/log-odds scale to obtain *odds ratios*, but applying the inverse link (usually logistic function) is rarely correct.
- `binomial()$linkinv(model.matrix(m) %*% fixef(m))` is indeed computing the predicted estimates on the link scale and converting them back to the data (= probability) scale.  You can get the same results more reliably (handling missing values, etc.) by using `predict(m, type = "response", re.form = ~0)` (this extends @Oliver's answer to a case that also applies the inverse-link function for you).
- I don't know what `binomial_pred_ci` is either, but I would suggest you look at `predictInterval()` from the `merTools` package ...

PS these answers all have not much to do with `runjags`, which uses an entirely different model structure.  Presumably `glmer` models are being  fitted for comparison ...

Answer (score 2):

`help(binomial)` describes the link function and inverse link function and their uses. `binomial()$linkinv` is the binomial inverse-link function (sigmoid function) `prob(y|eta) = 1 / (1 + exp(-eta))` where eta is the linear predictor. Using this with the coefficients (or fixed effects) is a bit odd, but is not unusual to get an idea of how large the effect of each coefficient is. I would not encourage it however.

`%*%` is the matrix multiplier, while `model.matrix(m)` (for lme4)  extracts the fixed effect model matrix. So `model.matrix(m) %*% fixef(m)` is the linear predictor using only fixed effects. It would be the same as `predict(m, re.form = ~ 0)`. This is often used in case you want to use the fixed effect model either because you want to correct for between-group-variation or because you are predicting new data.

`binomial_pred_ci` no idea. Guessing it's a function for predicting confidence levels.